# Cleaning your body of Creatine and Amino Acids

Tags: health, supplements, health-risk

How many days does the body need to get rid of all Creatine and Amino Acids?

Is not using any Creatine and Amino Acids for a week is enough to clean Liver and Kidney of these supplements? If not then how long needed?

Comment: Creatine is naturally produced by the body. Amino acids (assuming you mean Branched Chain Amino acids or  L-Glutamine) are found in protein. Both can be found in food. You are never truly "clean" of them, so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I think the more important question here is; why would you want to get rid of them? What have you heard, and from where?

Comment: Based on what I heard from a friend is that I have to take break from supplements and give my body rest to clean itself from it. I asked a doctor and he advised to drink lots of water to clean liver and kidney.

Comment: You doctor is correct, water helps flush out your kidneys. Your friend needs to read more before opening their mouth, they don't understand basic biology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creatine, [about 16.5 hours](http://mentalhealthdaily.com/2015/12/12/how-long-does-creatine-stay-in-your-system/):

> If you’ve recently ceased exogenous creatine supplementation due to adverse effects and/or (relatively unwarranted) concerns that it may cause kidney damage, you may be highly concerned with the duration it is likely to stay in your system.  To determine how long exogenous creatine stays in your system after discontinuation, it is necessary to examine its elimination half-life.  The elimination half-life of creatine is approximately 3 hours, indicating that 50% of a dose will be cleared from your plasma at roughly 3 hours post-ingestion.
>
> With this information we can calculate that 100% of exogenously administered creatine should be out of your system within 16.5 hours of your final dose.  In other words, after 24 hours have passed since your last creatine dose, there won’t be any lingering exogenous creatine in your plasma.  Exogenously administered creatine does form metabolites including: phosphocreatine (67%) and creatinine (2%).

We can't really answer for a general question of "amino acids" that you've taken, but I suspect that the answer isn't much different.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are referring to creatine and amino acids as supplements? As mentioned above, these are both naturally occurring in the body and in food. For example, higher amounts of creatine can be found in beef.

If you are talking about supplements, there is effectively no straight answer as it will depend on how your body reacts to the supplements and how much you have taken and how you have taken them. If you have saturated levels of creatine in your system, this would take longer to deplete than if not. As a reference point, you can absorb upto ~5g of creatine at one time; any more is passed through the urine.

I am not a doctor but generally speaking, it will take 1-2 weeks having stopped taking supplements for the creatine and amino acid levels in your body to return to its base level.
This is based on personal experience and speaking to health professionals.

Comment: By "personal experience" do you mean that you had clinical levels drawn at various points to confirm a return to pre supplement levels? Or by "personal experience" do you mean wild guess?